# Android Button background color when clicked

Tags: android, button, android-button

Can anyone help me with changing the background color of my button so that it can change color when clicked and change back to normal color after clicked.  I am not interested in using images and have looked, everyone keep posting half the codes so I still don't understand fully. If possible, please provide a link where I can see step by step instructions, These half posted comments does not help me at all because I am totally new to android and Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [question about change the colours of a button when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301029/question-about-change-the-colours-of-a-button-when-clicked)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make special drawable for that with selector element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and in the button

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<item 
    android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/item selected"/>
<item 
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/item selected"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Put this xml in a drawable file and set the resource.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but like I said, reference and examples to file names and what to put where.  The actual android site is confusing and is not for beginners.  A practical example is what I need.  In what  file does the items go and where else do I need to reference this e.g. in main activity.java.  You see this means nothing to me because I am learning and I cannot make this thing work.